# CGAffineTransformscale formula when size is known

Tags: scale, cgaffinetransform

I have to animate a UIImageView from a certain large width and height to a known smaller width and height in a given number of steps of time eg 10 steps or 20. I am using CGAffineTransformscale, but am unable to figure how how to compute the steps by which the individual downscales should happen. Is there a formula that you can share with me?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, a practical use for logarithms.

Remember that

```
log(X^Y) = log(X) * Y
```

So

```
log(X) = log(X^Y) / Y
```

So

```
X = exp(log(X^Y) / Y)
```

In this case, X is the scale to make at each step.  Y is the number of steps.  X^Y is the total scale you want to make.  For example,

```
Steps = 10;
TotalScale = 0.5;
ScaleEachTime = exp(log(TotalScale) / Steps);
```

gives (dots... because I am rounding off in the example)

```
              = exp(log(0.5) / 10)
              = exp(-0.693... / 10)
              = exp(-0.0693...)
              = 0.9330....
```

So scaling 10 times by 0.9330... gives a total scale of 0.5

Comment: First of all, pls accept my deepest thanks for taking the time out to actually explain this. I'm sure I will not be forgetting this in a hurry! :-) This worked absolutely fine!!! I computed the Total scale based off the length and breadth difference between the source and the destination images and then applied the formula!